# Help with multi-picklist query error

Tags: api, query, excel

I'm trying to build a query to import data into Excel, and am getting thrown errors everytime I try to limit the query based on a multi picklist. The field in question is "Summit_History__c". I can get the query to work when I use this:

```
SELECT Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c Includes ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')
```

I can also use an Inner Join to get all of my data, without the picklist restriction, using this query:

```
SELECT Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
INNER JOIN Account
ON Account.ID=Contact.AccountID
```

But as soon as I try to do both the table join AND the multi pick-list restriction, I get errors. This is my query:

```
SELECT Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
INNER JOIN Account
ON Account.ID=Contact.AccountID
WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c Includes ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')
```

A SQL syntax checker tells me that the last line has a "missing EOF" but I don't know what that means or how to fix it. Help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use "INNER JOIN" in SOQL. For that, you'd use a relationship or just query the Contact.AccountId as there is only one Account per Contact (it's Parent->Child). Just to confirm - are performing this query in Excel or in Salesforce?

Comment: Charley, are these queries excell functionality or part of a certain salesforce related plugin ? The queries you show appear to indicate that this isn't really related to anything salesforce specific ? You may have better luck getting an answer on stockoverflow.com or superuser.com

Comment: The suggested answers below work for my Excel connection, but I get an error in Access still. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your SOQL with correct syntax:

SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c  Includes  ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')

You can take a look at SOQL SELECT syntax [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks! This works for my Excel connection, but I get an error in Access still. Any reason why?

Comment: Hi. If you are getting another error not related to your question please add a new question as well as if the answer helped you please mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an Inner Join syntax in Soql. There are 2 ways in which relationships can be accessed in Salesforce.
**1. Child to Parent:** 
So in case you are trying to access an Account field while writing a query on Contact then you can use it as

```
Select id, contact.account.name from Contact Limit 10
```

**2. Parent to Child:**
In this case you are trying to access the Contact records from Account and hence you would need a nested query i.e. subquery.

```
 Select Id, Name, (Select id, Name From contact) from account limit 10.
```

Try reading more about soql queries that involve relationships.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by others, you cannot use "INNER JOIN" in SOQL. Instead you should query on relationships. Try following query:-

```
SELECT Account.Name, LastName, FirstName, Email, Title, Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c Includes ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')
```

For more information on relationship queries in SOQL refer following articles:-

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm